# Solving the Diophantine Equation $x^2 - y! = 2001$ and $x^2 - y! = 2016$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I had recently faced a problem:

> Solve the Diophantine Equation $x^2 - y! = 2001$.

Solving it was quite easy. You show how $\forall y \ge 6$, $9|y!$ and since $3$ divides the RHS, it must divide the LHS and if $3|x^2 \implies 9|x^2$ and so the LHS is divisible by $9$ and the RHS is not. Contradiction. Hence, the only solution is $(45, 4)$.

That made me wonder, how we can solve the Diophantine Equation $x^2 - y! = 2016$. We *cannot* apply the same logic here. $2016$ is a multiple of $9$ and it is clear that $3|x$ and $9 \nmid x$. How do I proceed from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $2016= 2^5 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 7$, we can use the same argument with $2$ or $7$ instead of $3$.

With $2$ we have:

If $y \ge 8$, then $2^5 \mid y!$ and so $2^5 \mid x^2$. This implies that $2^3 \mid x$ and, since $2^6 \mid y!$, we'd have $2^6 \mid 2016$, which is false.

Therefore, we only have to test $y \le 7$. The only solution is $x=84, y=7$.

With $7$ we have:

If $y \ge 14$, then $7^2 \mid y!$ and so $7^2 \mid x^2$. This implies that $7^2 \mid x$ and we'd have $7^2 \mid 2016$, which is false.

Therefore, we only have to test $y \le 13$. The only solution is $x=84, y=7$.

With $3$, the argument is similar to the one for $2$: If $y \ge 9$, then $3^4 \mid y!$.

Comment: Oh! So we'll have to handcheck for solutions till $y > 14$. Thanks.

Comment: $2$ also works.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Does it? $4|2016$.

Comment: $2016=63\times 32$

Comment: @QuangHoang Nope. $2016 \neq 61 \times 32$.

Comment: Sorry, typing on mobile sucks. I think that's what @lhf means.

Comment: The argument is not similar I think. I think that the logic only works on the primes with odd exponents.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use $\pmod{27}$.

We know that if $u\geq9$, then $27\mid n!$, and $2016\equiv18\pmod{27}$(as $45^{2}=2025$ is divisible by $27$).

$27$ is equal to $3^{3}$. Let’s say we have $x^{2}\equiv a\cdot b^{2c}\pmod{b^{2n+1}}$. Now if $n>c$, then this equation will only be solvable iff $a$ is a quadratic residue $\pmod{b}$.

For example, $x^{2}\equiv7^{2}\cdot5\pmod{7^{2}}$ is solvable, but $x^{2}\equiv7^{2}\cdot5\pmod{7^{3}}$ is not. This is because after dividing it by $7^{2}$, we get a number that is $5\pmod{7}$, and $5$ is not a quadratic residue $\pmod{7}$. In this case, $a=5, b=7, c=2, n=1$.

Let’s go back to the question; since we know that $2016\equiv18\pmod{27}$, then $x^{2}-y!=2016$ does not have positive integer solutions when $y\geq9$, because $27\mid y!$(if $y\geq9$), and $y!+2016\equiv18\pmod{27}$ when $y\geq9$, but $18$ isn’t a quadratic residue $\pmod{27}$, as after dividing it by $9$, we get a number that is $2\pmod{3}$, which is a contradiction, since all squares numbers are either $0,1\pmod{3}$.

Now, the only possibilities is that when $y\leq8$, and via Pari GP, we see that $x=84$ and $y=7$ are the only possible positive integer solution to $x^{2}-y!=2016$.

Bonus:

We can also use prime numbers to solve this.

The least prime number $p$ such that $x^{2}\equiv2016\pmod{p}$ is not solvable is $p=17$.

As you know, $17\mid2040$(because $17\cdot12=204$), so $2016-2040=-24$, hence $2016\equiv-24\equiv-7\equiv10\pmod{17}$.

However, $10$ isn’t a square $\pmod{17}$, as $10$ is a quadratic residue to prime numbers $p$ if $p\equiv1, 3, 9, 11, 13, 27, 31, 37, 39\pmod{40}$, but $17\equiv17\pmod{40}$. Alternatively, you could use quadratic reciprocity or check what is $1^{2},2^{2},3^{2},\cdots,8^{2}\pmod{17}$. If $10$ does not appear on the list, then it is not a square $\pmod{17}$.

Because of that, $x^{2}-y!=2016$ has no solutions when $y\geq17$.